# Order summary showing Zero subtotal checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, addtocart

Order summary are showing zero subtotal on both cart page and checkout page. I have checked error log but i can't fin anything related to my issue. you can also view what i meant here https://vimeo.com/773253273
Note: i have disabled all third party extensions, i am currently using Rokantheme complex multipurpose theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to create a patch for it. And it's a local issue.**

> 1. Install package for managing patches in composer:

```
composer require cweagans/composer-patches --ignore-platform-reqs
```

> 2. Create a new patch file using the below command. [copy this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ihor-sviziev/magento2/82c1a4d1137f747b9551e7d4d87106bf2c726b9e/app/code/Magento/Directory/Model/Currency.php) (file A) and also copy your vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php file (file B). Temporarily create a new folder and move both file A and file B. open the terminal that file location and run the below command.

```
diff -u Currency.php CurrencyUpdate.php > fix_price_zero.patch
```

> 3. Now Copy that fix_price_zero.patch file and create a new folder in root Magento name: **patches**, paste your fix_price_zero.patch file here.

> 4. Add the below content into the composer.json file

```
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override",
    "patches-file": "composer-patches.json",
    "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true
}
```

> 5. Create a new **composer-patches.json** file at Magento root and add the below content.

```
   {
       "patches": {
        "magento/module-directory": {
            "Price hotfix": "patches/fix_price_zero.patch"
        }
      }
    }
```

> 6. Then run below command and patch is applied.

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Reference Links

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33798

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34139

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/33966/commits/82c1a4d1137f747b9551e7d4d87106bf2c726b9e

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34799

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33856

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34229

https://pandagroup.co/blog/composer-patches-in-magento-2/

***Update***

MY PATACH FILE **fix_price_zero.patch**

```
--- a/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php    2022-07-21 08:45:08.000000000 +0530
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php    2022-11-21 15:27:16.005540428 +0530
@@ -11,9 +11,9 @@
 use Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Filter;
 use Magento\Framework\Locale\Currency as LocaleCurrency;
 use Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface as LocalResolverInterface;
+use Magento\Framework\NumberFormatter;
 use Magento\Framework\NumberFormatterFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
-use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
 
 /**
  * Currency model
@@ -28,11 +28,11 @@
     /**
      * CONFIG path constants
      */
-    public const XML_PATH_CURRENCY_ALLOW = 'currency/options/allow';
+    const XML_PATH_CURRENCY_ALLOW = 'currency/options/allow';
 
-    public const XML_PATH_CURRENCY_DEFAULT = 'currency/options/default';
+    const XML_PATH_CURRENCY_DEFAULT = 'currency/options/default';
 
-    public const XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE = 'currency/options/base';
+    const XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE = 'currency/options/base';
 
     /**
      * @var Filter
@@ -40,6 +40,8 @@
     protected $_filter;
 
     /**
+     * Currency Rates
+     *
      * @var array
      */
     protected $_rates;
@@ -85,7 +87,7 @@
     private $numberFormatterFactory;
 
     /**
-     * @var \Magento\Framework\NumberFormatter
+     * @var NumberFormatter
      */
     private $numberFormatter;
 
@@ -146,14 +148,11 @@
         $this->_localeCurrency = $localeCurrency;
         $this->currencyConfig = $currencyConfig ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(CurrencyConfig::class);
         $this->localeResolver = $localeResolver ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(LocalResolverInterface::class);
-        $this->numberFormatterFactory = $numberFormatterFactory ?:
-            ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(NumberFormatterFactory::class);
+        $this->numberFormatterFactory = $numberFormatterFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(NumberFormatterFactory::class);
         $this->serializer = $serializer ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Json::class);
     }
 
     /**
-     * Initializing Currency Resource model
-     *
      * @return void
      */
     protected function _construct()
@@ -255,10 +254,10 @@
     /**
      * Convert price to currency format
      *
-     * @param float $price
-     * @param mixed $toCurrency
-     * @return float
-     * @throws LocalizedException
+     * @param   float $price
+     * @param   mixed $toCurrency
+     * @return  float
+     * @throws \Exception
      */
     public function convert($price, $toCurrency = null)
     {
@@ -268,7 +267,7 @@
             return (float)$price * (float)$rate;
         }
 
-        throw new LocalizedException(__(
+        throw new \Exception(__(
             'Undefined rate from "%1-%2".',
             $this->getCode(),
             $this->getCurrencyCodeFromToCurrency($toCurrency)
@@ -276,10 +275,7 @@
     }
 
     /**
-     * Return the currency code
-     *
      * @param mixed $toCurrency
-     *
      * @return string
      * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
      */
@@ -353,11 +349,8 @@
     }
 
     /**
-     * Return formatted currency
-     *
      * @param float $price
      * @param array $options
-     *
      * @return string
      */
     public function formatTxt($price, $options = [])
@@ -428,18 +421,17 @@
         $this->numberFormatter = $this->getNumberFormatter($options);
 
         $formattedCurrency = $this->numberFormatter->formatCurrency(
-            $price,
-            $this->getCode() ?? $this->numberFormatter->getTextAttribute(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE)
+            $price, $this->getCode() ?? $this->numberFormatter->getTextAttribute(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE)
         );
 
         if (array_key_exists(LocaleCurrency::CURRENCY_OPTION_SYMBOL, $options)) {
             // remove only one non-breaking space from custom currency symbol to allow custom NBSP in currency symbol
-            $formattedCurrency = preg_replace('/ /u', '', $formattedCurrency, 1);
+            $formattedCurrency = preg_replace('/ /u', '', $formattedCurrency, 1);
         }
 
         if ((array_key_exists(LocaleCurrency::CURRENCY_OPTION_DISPLAY, $options)
-            && $options[LocaleCurrency::CURRENCY_OPTION_DISPLAY] === \Magento\Framework\Currency::NO_SYMBOL)) {
-            $formattedCurrency = str_replace(' ', '', $formattedCurrency);
+                && $options[LocaleCurrency::CURRENCY_OPTION_DISPLAY] === \Magento\Framework\Currency::NO_SYMBOL)) {
+            $formattedCurrency = str_replace(' ', '', $formattedCurrency);
         }
 
         return preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$/u', '', $formattedCurrency);
@@ -449,15 +441,14 @@
      * Get NumberFormatter object from cache.
      *
      * @param array $options
-     * @return \Magento\Framework\NumberFormatter
+     * @return NumberFormatter
      */
-    private function getNumberFormatter(array $options): \Magento\Framework\NumberFormatter
+    private function getNumberFormatter(array $options): NumberFormatter
     {
-        $locale = $this->localeResolver->getLocale() . ($this->getCode() ? '@currency=' . $this->getCode() : '');
-        $key = 'currency_' . hash('sha256', $locale . $this->serializer->serialize($options));
+        $key = 'currency_' . md5($this->localeResolver->getLocale() . $this->serializer->serialize($options));
         if (!isset($this->numberFormatterCache[$key])) {
             $this->numberFormatter = $this->numberFormatterFactory->create(
-                ['locale' => $locale, 'style' => \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY]
+                ['locale' => $this->localeResolver->getLocale(), 'style' => \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY]
             );
 
             $this->setOptions($options);
@@ -477,13 +468,13 @@
     {
         if (array_key_exists(LocaleCurrency::CURRENCY_OPTION_SYMBOL, $options)) {
             $this->numberFormatter->setSymbol(
-                \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL,
-                $options[LocaleCurrency::CURRENCY_OPTION_SYMBOL]
+                \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, $options[LocaleCurrency::CURRENCY_OPTION_SYMBOL]
             );
         }
         if (array_key_exists(LocaleCurrency::CURRENCY_OPTION_DISPLAY, $options)
             && $options[LocaleCurrency::CURRENCY_OPTION_DISPLAY] === \Magento\Framework\Currency::NO_SYMBOL) {
             $this->numberFormatter->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL, '');
+            $this->numberFormatter->setPattern(str_replace('¤', '', $this->numberFormatter->getPattern()));
         }
         if (array_key_exists('precision', $options)) {
             $this->numberFormatter->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::FRACTION_DIGITS, $options['precision']);
@@ -501,15 +492,13 @@
     }
 
     /**
-     * Return the price format to be displayed to user
-     *
      * @return string
      */
     public function getOutputFormat()
     {
         $formatted = $this->formatTxt(0);
-        $number = $this->formatTxt(0, ['display' => \Magento\Framework\Currency::NO_SYMBOL]);
-        return $formatted !== null ? str_replace($this->trimUnicodeDirectionMark($number), '%s', $formatted) : '';
+        $number = str_replace($this->getCurrencySymbol(), '', $formatted);
+        return str_replace($this->trimUnicodeDirectionMark($number), '%s', $formatted);
     }
 
     /**
@@ -545,8 +534,6 @@
     }
 
     /**
-     * Retrieve base config currency data by config path.
-     *
      * @return array
      */
     public function getConfigBaseCurrencies()
@@ -586,13 +573,13 @@
      * This method removes LRM and RLM marks from string
      *
      * @param string $string
-     * @return $this
+     * @return string
      */
-    private function trimUnicodeDirectionMark($string)
+    private function trimUnicodeDirectionMark(string $string): string
     {
         if (preg_match('/^(\x{200E}|\x{200F})/u', $string, $match)) {
-            $string = preg_replace('/^'.$match[1].'/u', '', $string);
+            $string = preg_replace('/^' . $match[1] . '/u', '', $string);
         }
         return $string;
     }
-}
+}
\ No newline at end of file
```

Comment: thanks for your response @Msquare, but i am getting a strange error after i did everything and i ran this command composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
Error: Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch patches/fix_price_zero.patch


  [Exception]
  Cannot apply patch Price hotfix (patches/fix_price_zero.patch)!

Comment: I added my patch file there please check it, May be you miss file path , Please add file path like above.

Comment: where do i add this file you sent because i have creted two files fileA and fileB and run this command diff -u fileB fileA > fix_price_zero.patch.

Comment: which folder or file should i add this please

Comment: @Adex can you connect me with skype ?

Comment: thanks a lot, what is your skype address

Comment: you can connect with me at Uthman Adenola or live:.cid.d94bcdd771fe0809

Comment: Please check my profile there is an option to connect me or click here. https://join.skype.com/invite/nkVHQ28bB2M6

Comment: We forgot to add path in our patch file you can see in above : a/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php Please update path after created patch file